# Mongo express show more than 10 rows per collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm a massive noob so please excuse me on this question if it's too dumb

I use [mongo express](https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express) to visualize my database and do some direct changes. The thing with mongo express is that it shows only 10 rows per collection. And the pagination systems isn't really helpful if you thousands of rows.

My question is simple: does anyone know of any way to see more than 10 rows per collection? I'm looking for an effect similar to [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) without having. Is there a plugin or anything you can help me with?